# Parse RDF XML file to get all rdf:about values

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml, rdf

I am using php's simple xml and xpath to parse an rdf xml file and am struggling to get a list of all the rdf:about values.

Any advice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There seems to be an issue when using SimpleXml with namespaced attributes prior to PHP5.3. Basically, anything with a `:` will be dropped when converted to an object property of a SimpleXml element. The following will do, but feels hackish to me:

```
$rdf = str_replace('rdf:about', 'rdf_about', $rdf);  
$rdf = new SimpleXMLElement($rdf);
foreach($rdf->xpath('//@rdf_about') as $node) {
  echo $node, PHP_EOL;
}
```

See here:

- http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.php/browse_thread/thread/d2a9b29ee21f7403/c6b24b6d398ece2c

You could use DOM instead of SimpleXml:

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadXml($rdf);
$xph = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xph->registerNamespace('rdf', "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#");
foreach($xph->query('//@rdf:about') as $attribute) {
    echo $attribute->value, PHP_EOL;
}
```

But, I suggest using a dedicated library for this over SimpleXml or DOM:

- http://arc.semsol.org/docs/v2/parsing
- http://www.seasr.org/wp-content/plugins/meandre/rdfapi-php/doc/
- http://librdf.org/raptor/
- http://phpxmlclasses.sourceforge.net/show_doc.php?class=class_rdf_parser.html

And here's a blog post about the parsers:

- http://www.wasab.dk/morten/blog/archives/2004/05/31/easy-rdf-parsing-with-php

Comment: Using Dom has proved much more successful - thanks.  I am using an arc triplestore and have looked into using its parser but all i want are the elements of a few ontologies and the arc parses seems to want to just provide a list or triples.

Comment: @David Haven't worked with ARC yet, so I can't tell much about it. You could ask http://twitter.com/bengee if it's possible though.

Comment: I might do but I have it working now using Dom intead of simple xml.  Thansk for all your help.