# Using PHP regular expressions to extract a value from an XML Schema

Tags: php, xml, regex, xsd

Using PHP Regular Expression I want to extract some value from code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="001">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Accountancy</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:enumeration>
                <xs:enumeration value="002">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Advertising</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:enumeration>
                <xs:enumeration value="005">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Amusement</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:enumeration>
            </xs:enumeration>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:schema>
```

I want to extract value 001 from

```
<xs:enumeration value="001">
```

For all tag

And text 'Accountancy' from

```
<xs:documentation>Accountancy</xs:documentation>
```

Using php reg ex match

how do I do this?

Comment: Use an xml parser

Comment: its not working due to semi column here xs:enu...

Comment: It's called namespace and yes, it's working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SimpleXmlElement and XPath, getting empty array()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024197/simplexmlelement-and-xpath-getting-empty-array)

Comment: possible duplicate of [php xpath problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354345/php-xpath-problems/5354633#5354633)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing xml problem…](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523012/parsing-xml-problem/3523060#3523060)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse RDF XML file to get all rdf:about values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486722/parse-rdf-xml-file-to-get-all-rdfabout-values/2486820#2486820)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650125/how-to-parse-html-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for the first.

```
preg_match("/<xs:enumeration value=\"(\d+)\">/", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

And for the second

```
preg_match("/<xs:documentation>(.+)</xs:documentation>/", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

but XML parser would be a better solution. DOMDocument can handle it I think.

Comment: -1 There is absolutely **no point** to use Regular Expressions for this task.

Comment: Then why are you offering it? See, the OP accepted it and uses the wrong tool for the job now. Parsing information from XML files is a a solved problem. Instead of learning how to do it properly, the OP now uses the Frankenstein solution.

Comment: I'm not offering that solution I in fact offered DOMDocument, I just showed how he can get a needed value with Regex that's all.

Comment: this solution provides alot of empty in array ... how to remove

Comment: @Headshota no, you didnt. There is no DOM solution. You offered a Regex solution. You basically said: "Here is some Crack, but remember drugs are not good for your health".

Comment: its says Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier ':' in D:\Program Files\webserver\www\car.php on line 5

Comment: @user then why did you accept it? How about you finally look at the four linked duplicates below you question all showing how to do it properly. I assume you are smart enough to substitute arguments to a function?